# is possible to re-encrypt an embedded.mobileprovision file?

Tags: ios, mobileprovision

As title, is possible to put manually an udid in a decoded mobileprovision and re-encrypt it manually with some commands from command line without login and follow the ordinary procedure on apple member center?

Comment: I hope answer is NO, but you can re-sign whole ipa with another provision/key

Comment: This is one of those questions for which you will find little support in open forums.

Answer (score 1):

The provisioning profile must be signed by Apple for a device to accept it.

So while you could  create a new plist, with an extra UDID and then sign it - unless you have one of Apple's private keys - the new provisioning profile would not be recognised.